# ¿Como utilizo un calculo hecho en PHP en Javascript/AJAX? LARAVEL

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, ajax

Tengo un calculo completamente funcional en un Modelo (PHP) que imprime el resultado en una vista (blade), pero quiero usarlo en Javascript por que necesito que tambien haga e imprima ese calculo en tiempo real... Intente traer el calculo por Ajax pero literal solo trae el calculo y ya, de ahí no pase a mas ya que mis conocimientos en JS son limitados...

```
//EJEMPLO DE LA ECUACION
  public function equation()
  {
      // ... CONSULTA 
      $data = ModeloPrueba::select(
      // ... aqui consulta de los datos
      )
      // ... aqui los join de los datos
      ->first();

      $gen = $data->genero;
      $raz = $data->etnia;
      $age = Carbon::parse($data->f_nacimiento)->age;
      $lab = $data->laboratorio;

      if (!$lab) {
         return 0;
      }

      $resultado = 175 * pow($lab, -1.154) * pow($age, -0.203);

      if ($gen == 1) {
         $resultado *= 0.742;
      }

      if ($raz == 2) {
         $resultado *= 1.210;
      }

      return response()->json(round($resultado, 2));
  }
```

---

```
    //EJEMPLO DE ARCHIVO JS
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/admin/prueba/equation',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data); //imprime el resultado de la ecuacion en la consola
        },
    });
```

---

```
    //EJEMPLO DE RUTA DEL AJAX
    Route::post('/prueba/equation',  [Prueba::class, 'equation']);
```

---

```
     //EJEMPLO DE VISTA BLADE
     <div class="col-md-2">
        <b>Ecuacion:</b><br>
        <a>0</a>
     </div>
```

Entonces al ingresar un dato especifico (uno de los campos de la ecuación) en el formulario, ejecutar toda la ecuación y que se muestre

Comment: puedes utilizar el metodo `Math.pow()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al hallar poca información, borré esta pregunta. La restaure por que encontré la manera de hacer lo que había propuesto a hacer y quería compartir la información por si alguien mas necesitaba esto. Esto fue lo que hice:

La ruta ajax sigue siendo la misma

```
    //EJEMPLO DE RUTA DEL AJAX
    Route::post('/prueba/equation',  [Prueba::class, 'equation']);
```

---

Le agregue un id a donde quería setear el resultado de la ecuación

```
     //EJEMPLO DE VISTA BLADE
     <div class="col-md-2">
        <b>Ecuacion:</b><br>
        <a id="resultadoEcuacion">0</a>
     </div>
```

---

Con `$(document).on('keyup', '#resultado_lab', function ()` estoy ejecutando el ajax cada que ingrese numeros al input con id `resultado_lab` para que haga el calculo en tiempo real, hago las variables con los demas campos para el calculo y las llamo en `data:` para usarlas. Si la consulta fue exitosa, seteo con `.text` el resultado de la ecuacion (`response`) en el id (`resultadoEcuacion`) de la vista. Osea la linea: `$('#resultadoEcuacion').text(response);`

```
//EJEMPLO DE ARCHIVO JS
$(document).on('keyup', '#resultado_lab', function () { //ejecutar funcion/calculo al escribir en el campo deseado
    var age = $('#datosAge').val();      //variables con
    var gen = $('#datosGen').val();      //los campos que 
    var raz = $('#datosRaz').val();      //se usan para el
    var lab = $('#resultado_lab').val(); //calculo
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/admin/prueba/equation',
        data: { 'age': age, 'gen': gen, 'raz': raz, 'lab': lab }, //se envia y recibe de la funcion php "equation"
        success: function (response) {
            $('#resultadoEcuacion').text(response); //setea el resutado de la ecuacion en el blade
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

---

Y pues, en la funcion de la ecuacion (`public function equation`) se le agrega el `Request` para por medio de alli, enviar y recibir datos...

```
//EJEMPLO DE LA ECUACION
public function equation(Request $request)
{
    // ... CONSULTA 
    $data = ModeloPrueba::select(
    // ... aqui consulta de los datos
    )
    // ... aqui los join de los datos
    ->first();

    if ($request->lab) { //Si hay datos en JS hacer calculo con ellos
        $gen = $request->gen; //con el request
        $raz = $request->raz; //recibe los 
        $age = $request->age; //datos de la 
        $lab = $request->lab; //consulta ajax
    } else { //Si no, hacer el calculo con los datos de la consulta
        $gen = $data->genero;
        $raz = $data->etnia;
        $age = Carbon::parse($data->f_nacimiento)->age;
        $lab = $data->laboratorio;
    }

    if (!$lab) {
     return 0;
    }

    $resultado = 175 * pow($lab, -1.154) * pow($age, -0.203);

    if ($gen == 1) {
       $resultado *= 0.742;
    }

    if ($raz == 2) {
       $resultado *= 1.210;
    }

    return round($resultado, 2);
}
```

---

Espero haberme explicado de manera clara, aquí dejo este aporte. Buen día